# Binding wpf object property to class property - usual way doesnt work for me

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, code-behind

!
Hi guys. I have a problem =(
Binding like that (like everywhere in examples and answers here) doesn't work at my case:

```
Binding b = new Binding("MyTextPath");
b.Source = YourDataClass;
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay; 
myTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

So, I have an instance "_configVM" of my class "ConfigVM" and it has a property "name". Need to bind this property to the "TextBlock.Text". Here is my code:

```
  Binding _textBinding = new Binding("name");
  _textBinding.Source = _configVM;
  _textBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  TextBlock _textBlockUI = new TextBlock() { Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["treeTextBlock"] };
  _textBlockUI.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, _textBinding);
```

or another option:

```
  Binding _textBinding = new Binding();
  _textBinding.Source = _configVM;
  _textBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  _textBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("name");
  TextBlock _textBlockUI = new TextBlock() { Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["treeTextBlock"] };
  _textBlockUI.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, _textBinding);
```

Both don't work, I get blank "TextBlock".
Everything else is ok, because this code fills "TextBlock" with "name" (added **Text = _configVM.name**):

```
  TextBlock _textBlockUI = new TextBlock() { Text = _configVM.name, Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["treeTextBlock"] };
  _textBlockUI.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, _textBinding);
```

but I need to bind in TwoWay mode, not just assign the value on compiling

Comment: Why don't you use xaml?

Comment: Look at the debug output window. Are there binding errors?

Comment: i believe textblock text property cant be bound two ways, maybe what you want is textbox

Comment: There is List<ConfigVM> of instances created dynamically. Therefore it's impossible to bind in xaml, isn't it?

Comment: @cremor
Yep, error:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'name' property not found on 'object' ''ConfigVM' (HashCode=5815700)'. BindingExpression:Path=name; DataItem='ConfigVM' (HashCode=5815700); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: Are you sure the property really is named `name`? Usually properties in C# start with a upper case letter. Also make sure that the property is public.

Comment: @dnr3
OneWay mode didn't solve the problem. And binding errors...

Comment: @cremor
Yes, the property is public. Look at the 3d code block, when I just assign **Text = _configVM.name** it works.

Comment: can u post the vm codes and its initialization?

Comment: `Text = _configVM.name` does not prove that it is a property. The expression might as well use a public field.

Comment: "There is List<ConfigVM> of instances created dynamically. Therefore it's impossible to bind in xaml, isn't it?". That is of course possible. Just use an ItemsControl with an appropriate `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you all :) The problem is solved. I didn't write `{ get; set; }` for `name`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `ConfigVM` class like

```
public class ConfigVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and perhaps a main view model like

```
public class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConfigVM> ConfigItems { get; set; }
}
```

you may easily create an ItemsControl in XAML like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: hm, that's it! Works with `{ get; set; }` for `Name` but doesn't work without them. I should give a listing for that class at the whole beginning.
And thank you for example with `ItemTemplate`, it seems better and easier to do like that than into code behind.

Comment: Without the `{ get; set; }` it's not a property, but just a field. Binding only works with properties.